# Self Join and update

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to create a cron that do the following:

check all user referrer col where referrer_id is 0, then Join with user email and update the referrer_id with the joined user id. Here my code:

```
SELECT us.id usId
     , us.referrer usRe
     , us.referrer_id usReId
     , re.id reId
     , re.email 
  from users us 
  LEFT 
  JOIN users re 
    ON us.referrer = re.email
```

I have to finish the update part, the problem is that the Join give me wrong results, I get in all case the user id 1.

Did you find something wrong in that query?

Tnx

Comment: Sample data and desired results would be a big help.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this answer can work for you

```
UPDATE users as us INNER JOIN users as re 
ON us.referrer = re.email 
SET us.referrer_id = re.id 
WHERE us.referrer_id = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly:

```
update users u join
       users r
       on u.referrer = r.email 
    set u.referrer_id = r.id
    where referrer_id is null;
```